# How to get id of sqlite when recyclerview item clicked?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

Here is my doubt when i click recyclerview item need to get task id which i saved in sqlite how can i do this for example when i click recycler view need to pass that value to next page and need update that value how can i do this so far what i have tried is:

```
public class Task extends Fragment  {
    private static final String MY_PREFERENCE_KEY = "yogan";
    private List<Model_Task_List> model_task_lists;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Task_List_Adapter taskadapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RequestQueue yog;
    String user_id;
    AppController app;
    RequestQueue queue;
    String Url;
    Task_DB task_db = null;
    Database_SF_APP database_sf_app;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        if (model_task_lists == null) {
            model_task_lists = new ArrayList<Model_Task_List>();
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        String hours=Integer.toString(hour);
        database_sf_app = new Database_SF_APP(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        int count=database_sf_app.getTaskCount();
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.login, 0);
        user_id = sharedPreferences.getString("user_id", null);
        model_task_lists=database_sf_app.getTaskListById(user_id);
        taskadapter=new Task_List_Adapter(model_task_lists,getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(taskadapter);
        if(taskadapter!=null){
            taskadapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Task_List_Adapter.data() {
                @Override
                public void yog(View v, int position) {


                }
            });
        }
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        Url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xx/xxx/GetActivitiesByUserID.svc/getlist/Task/" + user_id +"/" +null+"/"+hours;
        ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (nf != null && nf.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new JSONObject(),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            String server_response = response.toString();
                            try {
                                JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                                JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("TaskResult"));
                                for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                                    Model_Task_List modelobj = new Model_Task_List();
                                    JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    modelobj.setSubject(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Subject"));
                                    modelobj.setTaskID(json_arrayJSONObject.getInt("TaskID"));
                                    modelobj.setUserName(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("DueDate"));
                                    modelobj.setTaskStatus(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("TaskStatus"));
                                    modelobj.setUserid(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Owner"));
                                    database_sf_app.insertorUpdate(modelobj);


                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

            //Creating request queue

            queue.add(jsonObjRequest);

        }

        //sync operation
        //a union b
        //a server
        //b local storage

        //a only - insert local
        //b only - send to server
        //a = b do nothing

        //result
        //bind


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
            super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

Here is my TaskAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import java.util.List;

public class Task_List_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Task_List_Adapter.MyViewHolder>  {
    private List<Model_Task_List> dataSet;
    private    Context context;

    private static data yog;

    Model_Task_List modelTaskList=new Model_Task_List();

    public void remove(int position)
    {
        dataSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    public void edit(int position){
        dataSet.set(position, modelTaskList);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(data listener) {
        this.yog = listener;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        // Model_Task_List Model_Task_List=new Model_Task_List();
        TextView textname;
        TextView textaddress;
        TextView textphnum;
        TextView textdegree;
        TextView textemail;
        ImageView call;
        data datas;

        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            this.textaddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            this.textphnum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(yog!=null){
                        yog.yog(itemView,getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                }
            });

            // this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }



    }
    public interface data
    {
        void yog(View v,int position);
    }
    public Task_List_Adapter(List<Model_Task_List> data,Context context) {

        this.dataSet = data;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.task_list_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TextView textViewName = holder.textname;
        TextView textViewaddress = holder.textaddress;
        TextView textViewphnum = holder.textphnum;
        TextView textdegree = holder.textdegree;
        TextView textemail=holder.textemail;

        textViewName.setText("Subject:"+dataSet.get(position).getSubject());
        textViewaddress.setText("DueDate"+dataSet.get(position).getUserName());
        textViewphnum.setText("Status:"+dataSet.get(position).getTaskStatus());


    }




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

IS it right way to get id:

```
    taskadapter.setOnItemClickListener(new Task_List_Adapter.data() {
                @Override
                public void yog(View v, int position) {

Model_Task_List model_task_list=(Model_Task_List)model_task_lists.get(position);


                    String yog=model_task_list.getSubject().toString();
                   int yogeshs=model_task_list.getTaskID();
                    String yogan=Integer.toString(yogeshs);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),yogan,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
Where i make recyclerview clickable how to get id of sqlite when i click and need to pass the value to next page
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please post what you have tried other than this code you've included in the question.

Comment: check my edit when i click recycler view need to pass the value to next page with sqlite id

Answer (score 2):

The object you are displaying in recyclerview ,

in your case that code must be in TaskAdapter,

put id in that object so when you click on it you will get that object so retrieve ID from that object

```
clickedObjecj.getId();
```

Comment: is it the way get the id and to pass the value to next page

Answer (score 2):

defining onClick in the onBindViewHolder is not a good pratice

the correct way is that declare a interface in the adapter class and implement it on the Activity , Using interface we can pass the value

Steps 1:
 Decalre Listener for the OnItemClickListener interface

```
private OnItemClickListener mListener;
```

Step 2 : declare an interface , this interface will forward our click and data from adapter to our activity

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int elementId);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

Step 3 : define the on click on ViewHolder and pass the id

```
 //Assigning on click listener on the item and passing the ID value of the item
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // we can handle the click as like we do in normal
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int elementId = dataSet.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTaskID(); // Get the id of the item on that position
                        mListener.onItemClick(elementId); // we catch the id on the item view then pass it over the interface and then to our activity
                        }
                    }
            });
```

Step 4: implement `TaskAdapter.OnItemClickListener` in the activity

Step 6: onItemClick method you will recive the value

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(int itemId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: "+String.valueOf(itemId));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to set Cursor position into clicked one

```
Ex: Cursor products <- storing a set of data
```

to set Cursor to clicked position for example a position value from RecyclerView click event

```
products.moveToPosition(position);
```

then use getString as usual

```
String name = products.getString(products.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
```

hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, my problem just change setOnClickListener to setOnLongClickListener
i declare `puplic static int posit` in my Adapter
Second in onBindViewHolder of Adapter, i call:

`holder.layout_item.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { @Override public boolean online(View view) { posit = arrayList.get(position).getId(); return false; } });`
Next, on MainActivity, i want delete 1 object in sqlite
`Boolean checkDeleteData = phamTuanVan_sqlite.deleteData(PhamTuanVan_Adapter.posit);`
hope it may help